# chrome dev tool resource timing vs performance timing APIs

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools

I am comparing an html image resource timing come from chrome dev tool and performance timing API.

The end to end resource fetching time in chrome dev tool does match the performance timing duration. But not for others, such as TCP connection, domain lookup, etc… Any idea, Chrome bug (Version 54.0.2840.99 m (64-bit))?

Chrome Dev Tool -> Initial connection (TCP connection) -> 243.28ms

PerformanceTimingAPi -> 0 (connectEnd – connectStart = 0 -0 ?)

[see the capture of network trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZXaN.png)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same today with Chrome 61.0.3163.91.

I did not find any official answer on the Web, but I am pretty sure that it is because the Performance Timing API starts the measure from the navigationStart whereas the network Panel starts with the responseEnd (or something close when it starts parsing the HTML). The gap is always the same and is close to the gap between navigationStart and responseEnd.